# Access MasterPage public property in Design

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am setting a PATH for images in my web.config file. On each page, I am setting a public property like:

> ```
>     public string ImgPath
>     {
>         get { return Config.CDNImages; }
>     }
> ```

Then in the design page I use

```
<img src='<%#ImgPath%>/products/<%#Eval("prodID")%>.jpg'/></a>
```

It works, but now I want to add this public property on the MasterPage so I can access ImgPath on every page.

I cant seem to get the <%#ImgPath%> to work when the property in on the MasterPage.
I have tried <%#Master.Page.ImgPath%> .. and many other variation, but I cant seem to get it to work.

How do I get the public property within a MasterPage on a design page using in-line request/binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will work:

```
<%#Master.Page.ImgPath%>
 or
<%#Page.Master.ImgPath%>
```

Because `Page.Master` returns a base class, not the specific class of your master page, which means the ImgPath property won't be available without casting the `Page.Master` object. That would get very tedious to do every time.

Instead of adding the property to your master page, have you considered doing something like this?

```
public abstract class YourPage : Page
{
    public string ImgPath
    {
        get { return Config.CDNImages; }
    }
}
```

Now change your pages so they inherit from  `YourPage` instead  of `Page`, and you should have access to your method on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MasterType directive.

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/back-basics-%E2%80%93-using-mastertype